Cannot create database in PostgreSQL
I am a complete beginner on PostgreSQL, and I am following an introduction to databases to set up a local PostgreSQL database and connect to it. I am running Debian 15, so I do the following:
# apt update
# apt install postgresql

The installation is succesful. I then do:
sudo -u postgres psql
psql (15.7 (Debian 15.7-0+deb12u1))
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# \l
postgres=# createdb prismatest
postgres-# \l
postgres-# \c prismatest
connection to server on socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5433" failed: FATAL:  database "prismatest" does not exist
Previous connection kept

So the list of databases shows nothing and it is not possible to connect to the - supposedly - newly created database. My user has the rights:
postgres-# \du
                                   List of roles
 Role name |                         Attributes                         | Member of 
-----------+------------------------------------------------------------+-----------
 postgres  | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication, Bypass RLS | {}

Can anybody help me figure out what is going on? Thanks...

have you tried to read the documents? https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createdatabase.html - createdb iirc is the shell command to do it

i.e. use CREATE DATABASE prsimatest;

CREATE DATABASE "prismatest"; worked. Thanks, guys.

There are two different ways of creating a database in PostgreSQL. One is from the command line. The other is from the PostgreSQL console.
Command Line
In order to be able to create a database from the command line, you must first change to a user with rights to create a database. As you have shown with the \du command above, the user with those rights is postgres.
root@eric-desktop:/home/eric# su postgres
postgres@eric-desktop:/home/eric$ createdb prismatest2
postgres@eric-desktop:/home/eric$

As you can see, the creatdb command does not give any feedback. You need to confirm the creation by listing the current databases:
psql -U postgres -l
                                                 List of databases
    Name     |  Owner   | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    | ICU Locale | Locale Provider |   Access privileges   

-------------+----------+----------+-------------+-------------+------------+-----------------+-----------------------

 postgres    | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 |            | libc            | 

 prismatest  | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 |            | libc            | 

 prismatest2 | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 |            | libc            | 

PostgreSQL Console
Another possibility is to use the PostgreSQL console. To enter the console:
root@eric-desktop:/home/eric# sudo -u postgres psql
psql (15.7 (Debian 15.7-0+deb12u1))
Type "help" for help.
postgres=# 
postgres=# CREATE DATABASE "prismatest3";
CREATE DATABASE
postgres=# 

To confirm the creation of the database, list the databases:
postgres=# \l

                                                 List of databases
    Name     |  Owner   | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    | ICU Locale | Locale Provider |   Access privileges   

-------------+----------+----------+-------------+-------------+------------+-----------------+-----------------------

 postgres    | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 |            | libc            | 

 prismatest  | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 |            | libc            | 

 prismatest2 | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 |            | libc            | 

 prismatest3 | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 |            | libc            | 


Notice how the prompt has changed from the first line to the second:
        v
postgres=# createdb prismatest
postgres-# \l
        ^

psql is hinting that you are entering more lines of the same command.
Enter the semicolon (";") that terminates the create database statement.
postgres=# createdb prismatest ; 


createdb doesn't work at the postgres promt
postgres=# createdb prismatest2 ;
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "createdb"
LINE 1: createdb prismatest2 ;
^
postgres=# createdb "prismatest2";
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "createdb"
LINE 1: createdb "prismatest2";
^
postgres=#
